# Applying Style to Multiple Div's in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, styling

Apologies if this has been answered, I searched for about 30 mins and did not find the answer I was looking for.

I want to select multiple HTML divs into one variable and then apply styling to them upon an event.  I've tried setting variables like `boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = pickedColor;` but that throws an error of `i is not defined` and then I tried the code below and neither seem to work.

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
for (i in boxes) {
    boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
}
```

```html
<div class="header box"></div>
<div class="footer box"></div>
```

Any ideas, articles, or information will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you all very much and happy coding!

Comment: Have you tried using `document.getElementsByClassName("box")`? (jQuery is great for these kinds of problems by the way)

Comment: I hadn't tried that approach yet.  I wanted to do this project in "vanilla" JS, that's the only reason I didn't go with jQuery.  Thank you for the information though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for...in` iterates over enumerable properties in an object so it is not correct to use it in your case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

`querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, which has a handy `forEach` method:

```
boxes.forEach(box => box.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue");
```

Comment: Much thanks for your answer Mister Epic, that indeed worked.  Also, thank you for the info about the `for...in` information, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

Can you itterate a bit more verbose

```
for (let i= 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
     const element = boxes[i];
     boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
}
```

I'm not sure of syntax and have not tested your code, but it seems it could be that ?

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll` doesn't return an array. You can fix this like so:

```
var boxes = Array.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".box"));
for (i in boxes) {
    boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
}
```

or using the new ES2015 spread operator:

```js
const boxes = [...document.querySelectorAll(".box")];
for (const box of boxes) {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="header box"></div>
<div class="footer box"></div>
```

Comment: Why downvote this ?

Comment: it's unnecessary

Comment: @KevinB I still feel it's relevant, and at the most a comment saying why it's not necessary.

Comment: in my opinion that makes the answer not useful. meh. to each their own.

Comment: @KevinB I'm fine with that but everyday's a schoolday, dont expect someone to know why a downvote is made because you're more experienced ;) TEACH US!

Comment: I don't see a reason to convert something to an array when it can be iterated over just fine without doing so.

Comment: There are very good reasons for using for loops V forEach..

Comment: @KevinB: The properties of NodeList (specifically it being live) make it very prone to bugs by folks who treat it as an array. The OP for example. Converting it as such is a very common pattern and improves readability, which is an important facet of programming.